# Having issues with using a bootstrap dropdown toggle for a multi-option filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use a bootstrap dropdown toggle as a filter to change various controls. I'm able to get the links within the toggle to change the div with the controller in it, but I can't get the date selector to work that I'm attempting to for some reason.

Also - for some reason my two dropdown selectors won't change the default for some reason?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div style="float:left" class="col-md-3">
            <div class="">
                 <h5>Filter</h5>

                <div id="switcher" class="btn-group">
                    <button style="width:110px" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <span data-bind="label">Select One</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>

                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#week">Week</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#month">Month</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#stage">Stage</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#team">Team</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left" class="col-md-9">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="filter" id="week">
                    <div style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:15px;">
                         <h5>Week</h5>

                        <input style="width:200px" id="date-picker-1" type="text" class="date-picker form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="filter" id="month">
                    <div style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:15px;">
                         <h5>Month</h5>

                        <input style="width:200px" id="date-picker" type="text" class="date-picker-2 form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="filter" id="stage" class="" style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:15px;">
                     <h5>Stage</h5>

                    <button style="width:200px" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <span data-bind="label">Select Stage</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>

                    </button>
                    <ul style="margin-left:30px" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Stage 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Stage 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Stage 3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Stage 4</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="filter" id="team" class="" style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:15px;">
                     <h5>Team</h5>

                    <button style="width:200px" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <span data-bind="label">Select Team</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>

                    </button>
                    <ul style="margin-left:30px" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Team 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Team 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Team 3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Team 4</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/toomanyjulians/zh4trzgw/

Comment: What are you using for your datepicker? Neither the Bootstrap or jQuery which you are using in your fiddle have a datepicker.

Comment: Good spot! I've fixed that issue by adding bootstrap date-picker. Still having trouble with the dropdown not changing the default state....

http://jsfiddle.net/toomanyjulians/xyqu40ey/